# Javascript - Need to repeat array iteration that changes element's class every x seconds

Tags: javascript, arrays

I currently need to keep looping through an array using javascript.  The below is the one-way I can think of but 1-it doesn't work and 2- was wondering if their is a more optimal or compact way of achieving this?

```
var myArray=[1,2,3,4]

for (var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++)
{
     console.log(i + 'hi')
     if (i==3)
     {
        i=0;
     }

}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "keep looping through an array"? Like, forever? Just use a `while (true)` loop.

Comment: To get the value of the array at the index in your loop, do:  myArray[i], not i, which is just the loop iterator.

Comment: @Pointy Yes I can use while, but I want to keep iterating through myArray.  What is the best way to keep track of the current element and then go back to element 0

Comment: Even after you fix the reference to the array element with myArray[i], instead of i. You're going to have an infinite loop on your hands. Why do you want that?

Comment: At the end of the loop: `i = (i + 1) % myArray.length;`

Comment: *" 1-it doesn't work"* Looks like it would work. What doesn't work?

Comment: @ScottMarcus I'm trying to implement a loop that will display something every 10 seconds infintely.

Comment: @KingKongFrog well you're going to run into the problem of not being able to pause execution in JavaScript.

Comment: *" I'm trying to implement a loop that will display something every 10 seconds infintely"* Then using a **synchronous** loop is the wrong approach in the first place. Why don't you explain what you are trying to do in your question?

Comment: And you should mention this *"10 seconds"* part in your question.

Comment: To loop forever and restart whenever you reach the end of the array you can use: `for (var i = 0 ;; i = (i + 1) % array.length )`; of course, since Javascript is single-threaded you certainly don't want to loop forever, more likely you want to use `setInterval` or `setTimteout` to execute some code every 10 seconds.

Comment: if you want to display something every 10s infinitely, use `setInterval`

Comment: @KingKongFrog You will need to include setInterval() calls for the 10 second delay.

Comment: @FelixKling Sorry for the confusion.  Let's say I want to change the class of an element every 10 seconds.  The class names are in an array. That's theoretically what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of [Loop over array but with a time delay](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10965285/218196)

Comment: Before I start typing my comment, I see *"Avoid answering questions in comments"*, but I seem to be the only one :)

Answer (score 5):

Based on the comments you want to do something every 10 seconds:

```
// IIFE to keep the variable i contained to a new scope
+function ( ) {

    var DURATION = 10;
    var i = 0;

    setInterval( function ( ) {

        // Do something every ten seconds 
        console.log( arr[i] );

        // Increment i (mod array.length)
        i = (i + 1) % array.length;

    }, DURATION*1000 );

}();
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use the modulus operator

```
var i = 0;
// loop forever
while(true) {
    console.log(myArray[i] + 'hi');
    // i % 4 is the remainder when dividing i by 4
    // so this will cause i to be 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, ...
    i = (i + 1) % myArray.length;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It would be nice to know more about what exactly you need, but this is one approach:

```
function loop(arr) {
    for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        console.log('hi');
    }
    // OP wants a 10 second delay
    setTimeout(function () { loop(arr); }, 0);
}
```

## Edit:

Since it says in the comments you want a 10 second delay we can change the 0 in set timeout to 10000. The plus side to using setTimeout as opposed to an infinite loop is that it allows other event driven things to occur in the script.

Comment: For every 0 milliseconds do a for loop? Can you explain?

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez, first it iterates over the loop, then it calls the function again, but uses setTimeout to avoid recursion and a huge runtime stack. It's just another way of doing the loop infinitely.

Comment: But your loop runs for every 0 milliseconds. It must be: `setTimeout(function(){}, (10000));` Check the comments in the question.

Comment: @DannyFardyJhonstonBermúdez, the question doesn't say anything about the 10 seconds. However, as it does say that in the comments I have already mentioned changing the 0 to 10000 in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this could work.

```
function foo() {
    var myArray = [1,2,3,4],
        i,
        len = myArray.length;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
       console.log(i + 'hi');
    }
}
while(true) {
    setTimeout(foo, 10000);
}
```

Comment: This would "work" if your goal is to hang the browser :)

Comment: The problem with this is that since setTimeout is in the loop, it will get put into javascript's event queue infinitely. If you put `setTimeout(foo, 10000)` inside of foo, it will do what I think you are expecting.

Answer (score -2):

Check out the following:

var myArray=[1,2,3,4]

```
for (var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++)
{
     console.log(myArray[i] + 'hi')

     if (i==3)
     {
        i=0;
     }

}
```

You were missing `myArray[i]`

Another problem is that this is an infinite loop because if `i == 3` then it resets "i" back to zero causing your loop to never reach 4 ie. [1,2,3,4] ...just remove the if statement.